# Velocity Engine split() returns String instead of Array

Tags: maven, velocity, maven-archetype

I am using mvn archetype:generate to templatize some stuff in my project. I'm running into some trouble with the Maven 3.2.2 Velocity Engine split() method. I havent been able to figure out specifically what version of Velocity Maven is using.

```
#set($foo = "one:a, two:b, three:c")
$!foo
$foo.split(",")

#foreach($bar in $foo.split(","))
    $!bar
    $bar.split(":")

    #set($number = $bar.split(":").get(0))
    number = $!number

    #set($letter = $bar.split(":").get(1))
    letter = $!letter
#end
```

Expected output:

```
one:a, two:b, three:c
['one:a', 'two:b', 'three:c']

one:a
['one', 'a']
number = one
letter = a

two:b
...
```

Actual output:

```
one:a, two:b, three:c
[Ljava.lang.String;@6cff380

one:a
[Ljava.lang.String;@5a587f23
number =
letter = 

two:b
[Ljava.lang.String;@2c8b586a
...
```

As you can see, the first split() used in the #foreach block works as I expect splitting the string by commas and iterating over the three substrings, but when I print $bar.split(":") I get that weird String pointer and #set($number = $bar.split(":").get(0)) prints nothing because .get() is being called on a String instead of an Array. With that in mind I was able to come up with this horrible hack:

```
#foreach ($bar in $foo.split(","))
    #set ($i = 0)
    #foreach($hack in $bar.split(":"))
        #if($i == 0)
            #set ($number = $hack)
        #else
            #set ($letter = $hack)
        #end
        #set($i = $i + 1)
    #end
number = $number
letter = $letter
#end
```

But there has to be a better way, I cannot use this code in good conscience. I've been using Velocity for a grand total of 3 hours so I am surely to blame here, what does #foreach know that I don't?

Thanks for the help.

Edit: according to [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.archetype/archetype-common/2.2) maven archetype is using Velocity Engine 1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Ljava.lang.String;@6cff380` is not a string reference, it's a string array reference, so up to this point, eveything is normal (except maybe that Velocity could format the array instead of outputting its toString() method).

Then, when you call `get(i)` on an array, you don't get anything, whereas since Velocity 1.6 you *should* get what you want, that is the *ith* element. I just guess your version of Velocity is too old...

Comment: I thought after posting the [ might indicate an array, but wasnt sure. Thanks for lcarifying. I am pretty sure I am using Velocity Engine 1.5, the [documentation](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html) for which says it supports the .get(index) operation on Arrays, so not sure why it isnt working.

Comment: As I said in my answer, .get(index) only works since 1.6, so it is quite normal that it doesn't work in 1.5.

Comment: yeah, I found an actual [change log](http://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XWIKI-3142) for 1.6.2 that shows where they added get(index), yay documentation discrepancies!

Answer (score 0):

Claude's answer was helpful, but what if you can't use a newer version of Velocity?  I'm stuck with a version of Liferay that uses Velocity 1.5!

Velocity 1.3 and higher come with [ListTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.3/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ListTool.html), which can get the list members for you:

```
#set($number = $listTool.get($bar.split(":"),0)
#set($letter = $listTool.get($bar.split(":"),1)
```

That should give you your expected output.  It worked for me!